# Multiple display after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built a jQuery category filtration script that calls a WordPress calendar page with a category querystring. I get an issue that if I click the buttons too quickly, two instances of the calendar are shown. Currently the code uses a hidden checkbox so I don't think it's optimal. Can anyone see a better way to do this and could the code be simplified for efficiency?

```
$("#test").load("/events/cal-page/");
$("#catbox li").prepend("<input type=\"checkbox\"  style=\"display:none;\">  ");
$('.cat-item a').attr("href", "#")
$('.cat-item a').click(function() {
    $(this).prev().click();
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    //$(this).closest('a').find('[type=checkbox]').click();
});

$(":checkbox").change(function() {
    var values = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
        var bob = $(this).parent().attr('class');
        var bob = bob.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, ''); // Replace everything that is not a number with nothing
        var number = parseInt(bob, 10); // Always hand in the correct base since 010 != 10 in js    

        if (number == '2') {
            number = "5,6,7,8,13";
        } else if (number == '3') {
            number = "9,10,11,12";
        }
        //alert(number);    
        return number
    }).get();
    //alert(values);
    $("#test").load("/events/cal-page/?q=" + values + "");
});
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: Instead you can use jquery AJAX, where you can even abort the previous made request and only show the result of the current request.

Comment: Probably disabling the button for a while would be easier. You can add a loading spin to your button, and show it when clicked (disabling the button), then you enable it again after a while with `window.setTimeout()`. In this way, the user knows that his actions was recorded and is being processed